# How can I describe all matrices that can be written as a linear combination of three others?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the problem I am having trouble with.

[image: Valid XHTML]

I was able to find part a) without much trouble, but part b) has really stumped me. I don't know exactly how to solve for all matrices nor do I know how to put it into set notation. Once I can find the set/span, then finding a basis shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Any linearly independent set is _by definition_ a basis for its span. So (c) doesn't in fact depend on (b). (It is somewhat of a trick question).

Comment: For real numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma,$ carefully write out the matrix $$ \alpha M_1 + \beta M_2 + \gamma M_3 $$ and stare at it.

Comment: @WillJagy: What is the staring supposed to achieve? As far as I can tell, "$\alpha M_2+\beta M_2+\gamma M_3$" is as cromulent an answer to (b) as any.

Answer (score 2):

(b) Well, a matrix is a (say, $\Bbb R-$)linear combination of $M_1,M_2$ and $M_3$ if, and only if, it is of the form
$$
aM_1+bM_2+cM_3\quad(a,b,c\in\Bbb R).
$$
Therefore a description would be the set of all matrices of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a+b&b+c\\-a+2b+c&a+b\end{pmatrix}\quad(a,b,c\in\Bbb R).
$$

(c) Since $M_1,M_2$ and $M_3$ are linearly independent (you've shown it in (a)), it *is* a basis for $\text{Span}\{M_1,M_2,M_3\}$ (a basis is a generating, linearly independent set of vectors, and clearly $M_1,M_2,M_3$ generate $\text{Span}\{M_1,M_2,M_3\}$ by definition!).

Answer (score 1):

Write the combination $a M_1 + bM_2 + cM_3$, with $a,b,c \in \Bbb R$. You will have a matrix, whose entries depend on $a,b$ and $c$. The combinations are all of those matrices, as $a,b$ and $c$ range over $\Bbb R$. The third item seems really redundant since you already proved that $M_1,M_2$ and $M_3$ are linearly independent. They are themselves the basis you're looking for, but think a bit about it.